# How to move an imovie project from one computer to another?

Tags: imovie

I've been editing a video in macbook and it's running out of space..

How do I move the data to a new computer so that I can continue editing the video?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well, the YouTube video [iMovie: How to transfer iMovie Project Files Between Mac Computers and backing up iMovie files.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a45dWFzMmy4) helped.

Basically, you create a Library in iMovie, then copy the project into the Library.

I tested this up to the point where I saw it created a 200 MB iMovie file, I didn't test to make sure it imports and functions correctly.

Answer (score -1):

See this video - [How to Export an iMovie Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQeIj5XOp8o).

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant